# How do I convert 2018-04-10T04:00:00.000Z string to DateTime?

Tags: java, android-studio, datetime, datetime-format

I get a date from a JSON API which looks like this "2018-04-10T04:00:00.000Z". I want to convert it in order to obtain a Date or String object and get something like "01-04-2018" that its "dd-MM-YYYY". How can I do it?

Comment: Use `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: ...or use the Java 8 date API.  Either way, this is a duplicate.

Comment: @Arvind Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting. You can assume all the basic date-time Questions have been asked and answered already.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

#### Update: Using `DateTimeFormat`, introduced in java 8:

The idea is to define two formats: one for the input format, and one for the output format. Parse with the input formatter, then format with the output formatter.

Your input format looks quite standard, except the trailing `Z`. Anyway, let's deal with this: `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"`. The trailing `'Z'` is the interesting part. Usually there's time zone data here, like `-0700`. So the pattern would be `...Z`, i.e. without apostrophes.

The output format is way more simple: `"dd-MM-yyyy"`. Mind the small `y` -s.

Here is the example code:

```
DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH);
DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2018-04-10T04:00:00.000Z", inputFormatter);
String formattedDate = outputFormatter.format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate); // prints 10-04-2018
```

#### Original answer - with old API `SimpleDateFormat`

```
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date date = inputFormat.parse("2018-04-10T04:00:00.000Z");
String formattedDate = outputFormat.format(date);
System.out.println(formattedDate); // prints 10-04-2018
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Yes, you can use it on Android. For older Android see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: Right, Sir, updated the answer.

Comment: Acknowledged and upvoted, Tamas. As input formatter you may use [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME), so you don’t need to roll your own.

Comment: Thanks! This `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` is nice. Cannot use here unfortunately as OP has a literal `Z` in his input string. Probably they have formatting problems in other parts of their systems, that's why it's not a real time zone data. Anyway, that's a separate problem.

Comment: `LocalDate.parse("2018-04-10T04:00:00.000Z", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)` works nicely and gives `2018-04-10`. `Z` is a perfectly valid offset, widely used rather than +00:00.

Comment: Indeed. I thought it would work the same way `SimpleDateFormat` does. It's great to learn from comment on answers :)

Comment: The `Z` means that the date/time is in UTC, according to [ISO 8601's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)). As said by OleVV, it can be used when the offset is zero (+00:00). Using `SimpleDateFormat` with `Z` inside quotes makes it parse the Z as a literal (the letter Z), instead of parsing it as a zero-offset. The problem is that, in this case, `SimpleDateFormat` will use the JVM default timezone, and the `Date` will correspond to a wrong point in time.

Comment: @OleV.V. I'm not sure you can always rely on those nicer new Java date utilities always being available in Android.

Comment: @pyetti I don’t know the exact limit, but it is my understanding that the ThreeTenABP library works on pretty old Android versions too. You are right, the features are only built-in from API level 26, under that level you need the mentioned library.

Comment: It seems this way needs minimum API level 26. I'm wondering if there's a way to do this using functions from minimum API 23

Answer (score 10):

Using Date pattern `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'` and Java 8 you could do

```
String string = "2018-04-10T04:00:00.000Z";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(string, formatter);
System.out.println(date);
```

Update:
For pre 26 use Joda time

```
String string = "2018-04-10T04:00:00.000Z";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
LocalDate date = org.joda.time.LocalDate.parse(string, formatter);
```

In app/build.gradle file, add like this-

```
dependencies {    
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
}
```

Comment: works great but this call requires API Level 26 (current min is 15) on my Android app and I don't want to change it for now. There is another alternative?

Comment: This will work nicely on older Android too. For pre-level-26 see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).

Comment: Since the string is in ISO 8601 format, you don’t even need an explicit formatter. The `java.time` classes parse this format as their default. `LocalDate date = OffsetDateTime.parse(string).toLocalDate()`.

Comment: Joda-Time was a very good library. “Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. … If using Java SE 8, please migrate to java.time (JSR-310).” Quoted from [the Joda-Time homepage](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). So I recommend ThreeTenABP over Joda-Time.

Comment: Ole V.V is right. Joda time suggested to migrate to java.time. I didn't have the oppertunity to use the ThreeTenABP before, so I can not tell / suggest about it.

Comment: This Answer ignores the crucial issue of the me zone. For any given moment, **the date varies** around the globe by zone.